# React COREUI CChart problem not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, core-ui

I am having problem with CChart not rendering correctly. I am following this example:

https://coreui.io/react/docs/3.3/components/CCharts/

I am a beginner with react so it is probably a simple mistake but I cannot figure out what.

This is my code:

```
import React, { lazy } from "react";

import {
  CChart,
  CChartBar,
  CChartHorizontalBar,
  CChartLine,
  CChartDoughnut,
  CChartRadar,
  CChartPie,
  CChartPolarArea,
} from "@coreui/react-chartjs";

const Profile = () => {
  const line = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "My First dataset",
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0.1,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
        borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
        borderCapStyle: "butt",
        borderDash: [],
        borderDashOffset: 0.0,
        borderJoinStyle: "miter",
        pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
        pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
        pointBorderWidth: 1,
        pointHoverRadius: 5,
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
        pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
        pointRadius: 1,
        pointHitRadius: 10,
        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
      },
    ],
  };

  const bar = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "My First dataset",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
        borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
        borderWidth: 1,
        hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.4)",
        hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
      },
    ],
  };

  const doughnut = {
    labels: ["Red", "Green", "Yellow"],
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [300, 50, 100],
        backgroundColor: ["#FF6384", "#36A2EB", "#FFCE56"],
        hoverBackgroundColor: ["#FF6384", "#36A2EB", "#FFCE56"],
      },
    ],
  };

  const radar = {
    labels: [
      "Eating",
      "Drinking",
      "Sleeping",
      "Designing",
      "Coding",
      "Cycling",
      "Running",
    ],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "My First dataset",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(179,181,198,0.2)",
        borderColor: "rgba(179,181,198,1)",
        pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(179,181,198,1)",
        pointBorderColor: "#fff",
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#fff",
        pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(179,181,198,1)",
        data: [65, 59, 90, 81, 56, 55, 40],
      },
      {
        label: "My Second dataset",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
        borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
        pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
        pointBorderColor: "#fff",
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#fff",
        pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
        data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 96, 27, 100],
      },
    ],
  };

  const pie = {
    labels: ["Red", "Green", "Yellow"],
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [300, 50, 100],
        backgroundColor: ["#FF6384", "#36A2EB", "#FFCE56"],
        hoverBackgroundColor: ["#FF6384", "#36A2EB", "#FFCE56"],
      },
    ],
  };

  const polar = {
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [11, 16, 7, 3, 14],
        backgroundColor: [
          "#FF6384",
          "#4BC0C0",
          "#FFCE56",
          "#E7E9ED",
          "#36A2EB",
        ],
        label: "My dataset", // for legend
      },
    ],
    labels: ["Red", "Green", "Yellow", "Grey", "Blue"],
  };

  const options = {
    // tooltips: {
    //   enabled: false,
    //   custom: customTooltips
    // },
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
  };

  return (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-md-6">
        <h4>Line</h4>
        <div className="chart-wrapper">
          <CChart type="line" datasets={line.datasets} options={options} />
        </div>
        <hr />
      </div>
      <div className="col-md-6">
        <h4>Bar</h4>
        <div className="chart-wrapper">
          <CChart
            type="bar"
            datasets={bar.datasets}
            options={options}
            labels="months"
          />
        </div>
        <hr />
      </div>
      <div className="col-md-6">
        <h4>Doughnut</h4>
        <div className="chart-wrapper">
          <CChart
            type="doughnut"
            datasets={doughnut.datasets}
            labels={doughnut.labels}
          />
        </div>
        <hr />
      </div>
      <div className="col-md-6">
        <h4>Radar</h4>
        <div className="chart-wrapper">
          <CChart
            type="radar"
            datasets={radar.datasets}
            labels={radar.labels}
          />
        </div>

        <CChart
          type="radar"
          datasets={[
            {
              label: "2019",
              backgroundColor: "rgba(179,181,198,0.2)",
              borderColor: "rgba(179,181,198,1)",
              pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(179,181,198,1)",
              pointBorderColor: "#fff",
              pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#fff",
              pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(179,181,198,1)",
              tooltipLabelColor: "rgba(179,181,198,1)",
              data: [65, 59, 90, 81, 56, 55, 40],
            },
            {
              label: "2020",
              backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
              borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
              pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
              pointBorderColor: "#fff",
              pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#fff",
              pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
              tooltipLabelColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
              data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 96, 27, 100],
            },
          ]}
          options={{
            aspectRatio: 1.5,
            tooltips: {
              enabled: true,
            },
          }}
          labels={[
            "Eating",
            "Drinking",
            "Sleeping",
            "Designing",
            "Coding",
            "Cycling",
            "Running",
          ]}
        />
        <hr />
      </div>
      <div className="col-md-6">
        <h4>Pie</h4>
        <div className="chart-wrapper">
          <CChart type="pie" datasets={pie.datasets} labels={pie.labels} />
        </div>
        <hr />
      </div>
      <div className="col-md-6">
        <h4>Polar</h4>
        <div className="chart-wrapper">
          <CChart
            type="polarArea"
            datasets={polar.datasets}
            options={{
              maintainAspectRatio: true,
              tooltips: {
                enabled: true,
              },
            }}
            labels={polar.labels}
          />
        </div>
        <hr />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Profile;
```

This is what is displayed on the page:
[image]

I do not know why, I have tried a lot of different ideas but none work. Do any of you know how to fix this issue? Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you did a fresh install of chart.js, this will install V3 of the lib. This has some major braking changes over V2 of the lib which coreUI uses. So you will need to install V2 of chart.js and that should resolve your issue:

```sh
npm uninstall chart.js
npm install chart.js@2.9.4
```

```sh
yarn remove chart.js
yarn add chart.js@2.9.4
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add this:

> import '@coreui/chartjs/dist/css/coreui-chartjs.css'

or

```
import '@coreui/chartjs/dist/css/coreui-chartjs.css'
import '@coreui/coreui/dist/css/coreui.min.css'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
```

don't forget to install all npm packages

```
npm install @coreui/chartjs
npm install @coreui/coreui
npm install bootstrap
```